# Java Script DrobDown Disable Mark

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, optional-parameters, disabled-control

Here is my question, for exp:

```
 <select name="select1" >
 <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 <select name="select2" >
 <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
```

If I select (number 1) from (select1), then (select2) totally will be disabled. or if i select (number4) from (select2) then (select1) totally will be disabled. 
I mean depends on select name, other select name will be disabled.
Is it possible to give me the java code for this ?
Thank you

Comment: java code ? or javascript code ? pick one

Comment: really - this is something readily available on hundreds of websites. take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, it'd be something like this. [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sVMKy/)

HTML:

```
<select id="select1" name="select1" >
 <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 <select name="select2" id="select2" >
 <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 </select>
```

JS:

```
$('#select1').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() != 'default'){
        $('#select2').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
        $('#select2').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

$('#select2').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() != 'default'){
        $('#select1').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else{
        $('#select1').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

As I said, you need to correct your html as well. In your website, use the following html instead of what you have i.e. add ID's to your select dropdown.

```
<select id="select1" name="select1" ...
<select id="select2" name="select2" ...
```

Comment: I tried to put the jquery code into page, but there is no result, even in IE also I got error in Line 37. You can check this code in this webpage: [link](http://www.malayatourism.com/javatest.php)

Comment: I tried to put the jquery code into page, but there is no result, even in IE also I got error in Line 37. You can check this code in this webpage: (http://www.malayatourism.com/javatest.php)

Comment: include jQuery in your page like this  `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` because i do not see it yet included in your page.

Comment: Yes you are right, Code is working well. But I got another problem, when I put the code into my webpage, not working. I don't know what's problem. You can check it here (http://behdasht.co/wp/javatest.php)  however I put ajax link, but not working... Please guide me how to solve it. Thank you soo much.

Comment: Updated my answer..you need to use `<select id="select1" name="select1" ...` and `<select id="select2" name="select2" ...`

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to say thank you for your help. You are really good in the css. I really proud of you. Again Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: @Amin did the answer help you? If it did, request you to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Hi, I got another problem, I tried to solve it but unfortunately I couldn't solve it, In above matter, how can I use reset button, because when I click on reset button, it will change to default, but still one of items is disabled.  Here is my code: <button type="reset" class="right" onclick="document.forms['f1'].reset();">Reset</button>

Comment: My form name is (f1) , thats why I changed it to F1 , I'm waiting for your reply. thank you sooooo much for your help.

Comment: @Amin it does not make sense to continue within the same question anymore. Request you to update your question with more details as short comments are difficult to understand